# Efficiently Merging Lists of Lists

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net-4.0

I need a little assistance developing an algorithm that merges Lists of Lists based on matching like key/value pairs.

In the example below I have 3 List> instances which I would like to reduce/merge using a Merge method call.  The object of the Merge is to take instances that contain any matching key/value pair and merge both lists into a new list containing all of the pairs from both lists.  So in this example the Merge method should condense the 3 lists into 1 because list1 and list2 both containing matching key names and values for "key1" and "key2".  Then the new merged list of list1 and list2 would further merge with list3 because they both contain matching key names and values for "key4".

Anyone have any ideas on an efficient algorithm?  I'm currently using a recursive method that is extremely slow as it compares every list to every other list.

```
    var list1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { 
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key1","2"), 
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key2","5"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key3","20")
    };

    var list2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { 
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key1","2"), 
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key2","5"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key4","10"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key5","A"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key6","B"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key7","C")
    };

    var list3 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { 
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key10","2"), 
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key20","5"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key4","10"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key40","2")
    };

    var fullList = new List<IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();

    fullList.Add(list1); 
    fullList.Add(list2); 
    fullList.Add(list3);

    List<IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> mergedList = fullList.Merge();

    /*
     output should be a single a single IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> with a count of 10 KeyValuePair<string,string> items
     mergedList would contain the following key/value pairs

        "key1","2" 
        "key2","5"
        "key3","20"
        "key4","10"
        "key5","A"
        "key6","B"
        "key7","C"
        "key10","2" 
        "key20","5"
        "key40","2"
    */
```

Comment: Can you just use `HashSet.Union` or do you want to implement yourself?

Comment: What do you do in the case of KVPs where the keys match but the values differ?

Comment: @Nicholas - if the kays match but the values differ no merge should occur.  I only wish to merge when all shared keys have the same values across the 2 target lists in the comparison

Comment: @dotjoe - will HashSet.Union combine when all intersecting keys have the same values?

Comment: @njappboy...what do you mean "no merge should occur"? You throw an exception? toss the KVPs with values that don't match? Keep just one (and if so, which)?

Comment: @Nicholas - the non-merged lists remain in the full list of lists for further comparison.

Comment: @njappaboy it would depend on how `KeyValuePair` implements `Equals` you could certainly create you're own class to do it.

Comment: @dotjoe - I'm actually using my own class and IEqualityComparer to perform comparisons

Comment: Oh, just override `Equals` to account for the key and value...then you should be all good letting HashSet do the Union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this post on linq set operators http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/05/05/c.net-little-wonders-the-linq-set-operations----theyre-not.aspx

Comment: I'm basically using an implementation such as this but it seems to be very slow.

Comment: how big are your lists? I would suggest that the inbuilt LINQ implementation would be faster then what you have build yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use a `Dictionary<String, HashSet<String>>` to store the merged data.  This would allow you to quickly look up whether the output already contains the key you want, and if not add it (and, for it's value, a hashset containing the current item's value).  If the key already exists in the dictionary, simply take the value (a hashset) and call it's Add method, which already takes care of efficiently preventing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

IT sounds like you want to union the three lists from your description rather than get a list of lists e.g.

```
var list1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { 
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key1","2"), 
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key2","5"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key3","20")
    };

var list2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { 
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key1","2"), 
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key2","5"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key4","10"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key5","A"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key6","B"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key7","C")
    };

var list3 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { 
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key10","2"), 
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key20","5"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key4","10"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key40","2")
    };

var unionedList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

unionedList.AddRange(list1.Union(list2).Union(list3));

foreach (var kvp in unionedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));    
}
```

unionedList will now contain a distinct list of KeyValue pairs as per your expected output.  You will get duplicate keys if the values are different though.